# wkhtmltopdf in php exec not working in browser

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to get wkhtmltopdf to work with PHP.
I compiled wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2-dev (with patched qt) on debian 6.

it works when I am on the server (shell):

```
./wkhtmltopdf ./tmp.html output.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

it also works when the command is in a php file (exec ("./wkhtmltopdf ....")) and I call the php file in the shell:

```
php makepdf.php
```

But it does not work when I call the php file in my browser. return code from the exec is 127
That means that the wkhtmltopdf could not be found? I tried also to use absolute paths. verything is chmod +x

Any idea how to get wkhtmltopdf to work with php?

Comment: What's the output of `stat wkhtmltopdf`?

Answer (score 1):

Thats correct.

You call the wkhtml programm ober `./` use the complete path to the progam then its working.

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /tmp/tmp.html output.pdf`

for example.

http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/

Here is a wrapper. Perhaps you can use it and configure it.

Comment: yeah, I tried that. Also not working. :( - I guess it is a permission issue. In the shell I am logged in as root and it does not execute for www user

Comment: adding the full path of wkhtmltopdf worked for me tnx!!